# On the tidal heating of a moon. What is the second Love number?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, resource-recommendations, planets, tidal-effect, moon

Years ago it was asked [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/61059/) how to calculate the tidal heating of a moon orbiting another body with a simple equation. The answer is very detailed. They explain the equation, its shortcomings, the approximations made, the constants and variables used, etc.

The entire equation is proportional to a variable: −Im$(k_2)$. The answerer explains that it is the second Love number, part of a family of numbers which "are dimensionless parameters that measure the rigidity of a planetary body and the susceptibility of its shape to change in response to a tidal potential." [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love_number). This variable is hard to calculate, so they advice using known values, like for example the Moon or Io, which correspond to −Im$(k_2)=0.02$

The problem is that I couldn't found values for more Solar System bodies, or any reference on how −Im$(k_2)$ changes in function of density, mass, composition, or structure. I only found values for $k_2$, but nowhere I looked I found −Im$(k_2)$. Is there a useful source somewhere where I can find a table of −Im$(k_2)$ values for the planets, or studies that estimate the number in function of the type of planet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The International Earth Rotation and Reference Systems Service (IERS) maintains a list of parameters, available online [here](https://iers-conventions.obspm.fr/conventions_versions.php#official_target). Chapters 6 and 7 contain values of $Im(k_2)$ as well as detailed calculations.

Note that in some cases the second Love number is real, and in others it is complex.

You can also consult the following paper for information:

Zhang, C. Z. "Love numbers of the Moon and of the terrestrial planets." Earth, Moon, and Planets 56.3 (1992): 193-207.

Comment: @Stellar_Enginner Does this answer your question? I'd be happy to improve it if you provide feedback.

Comment: Yes thank you. I think the equation on the wikipedia page is wrong.